# PHP-destroy-session-on-close-of-main-window

Tags: php, session

How to destroy the session on closing the browser
When browser window is closed, session should be terminated. Right now, if I close the window and type the application url, it is allowing me to access application.

Comment: Be sure to distinguish between closing one browser window/tab and all of them

Comment: Specify browser type, php version, etc. please

Comment: both, its has to be expired at browser close or tab close. session.cookie_lifetime,0 in php.ini works in IE on browser close but not in firefox

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fixed.

With below settings "application" session expires during browser close.

Firefox Browser->Tools->Options->General Tab 
StartUp: When Firefox starts: Show a blank page

Firefox Browser->Tools->Options->Privacy Tab 
History: Firefox will Use custom settings for history / Never remember history 
Cookie: Keep Until : I close firefox

Comment: This is not a valid solution to the problem/question

Answer (score 2):

Native php sessions well expire on browser close. As long as you are not modifying the session cookie expiration time you should be fine.

If this is not happening then I am going to guess you are using a framework that is changing the php defaults or your php configuration has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really seem like altering your browser settings is an appropriate method for achieving this solution as it would only then work for users with said browser settings in place.